# I am Get starting with unit testing with NUnit, (doesn't run the test) Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

i am starting using unit testing in visual Studio. I'm reading the Microsoft Documantation about it: [Get started with unit testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/getting-started-with-unit-testing?view=vs-2019), but when i run, doesn't run the test, and show this: Program, is inaccessible due to its protection level. I dont know what i have to do now.
Can u help.

This is my Hello World Program

```
using System;

namespace demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Unit test with NUnit

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace HelloWorldTests
{
    public class Tests
    {
        private const string Expected = "Hello World!";

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                Console.SetOut(sw);
                demo.Program.Main();

                var result = sw.ToString().Trim();
                Assert.AreEqual(Expected, result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR SHOW: Error CS0122: 'Program' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122) (HelloWorldTests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your class program as public so it can be reach by your test project.

Comment: yes i did. And now: Main(string[] args) is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: So to follow that logic i would sugest setting you main method to public also.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite agree with the other answers. Don't make methods public just for testing purposes. This may break the encapsulation.

Instead, use the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all comments,

```
using System;

namespace demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }

    }
}
```